# VirtualAllocEx success return a base address,but then WriteProcess fails,and error is 487

Tags: c++, c, winapi, memory

My code.

```
int main()
{
HANDLE hTargetHandle;
int TargetProcessId=GetTargetProcessId();


hTargetHandle=OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,TargetProcessId);

if(hTargetHandle==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    DWORD d=GetLastError();
    printf("openprocess fail\n");
    printf("the TargetProcessId is: %d\n",TargetProcessId);

    printf("the result of getlast is: %d\n",d);
    system("PAUSE");
    exit(-1);
}

DWORD dwBufferSize=(DWORD)GetTargetProcessId-(DWORD)create;

DWORD dwProcBaseAddress=(DWORD)VirtualAllocEx(hTargetHandle,NULL,1024*1024,MEM_COMMIT,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);     //the size here is 1024*1024,I don't know the size of the function I am going to inject to another process,so I use 1024*1024 here.I have ever tried to use 1024*1024*10,but it is the same error.

if(dwProcBaseAddress==NULL)
{
    DWORD d=GetLastError();
    printf("virtualallocex has fail\n");
    printf("the last error is:%d\n",d);
    system("PAUSE");
    exit(-1);
}

int a=WriteProcessMemory(hTargetHandle,&dwProcBaseAddress,create,1024*1024,NULL);             //create is a function I defined,used to inject to another process.
if(a==0)
{
    DWORD d=GetLastError();
    printf("writeprocessmemory has fail\n");
    printf("the last error is %d\n",d);
    system("PAUSE");
    exit(-1);
}

DWORD dwThreadId;

HANDLE hRemoteThreadHandle=CreateRemoteThread(hTargetHandle,NULL,NULL,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)dwProcBaseAddress,NULL,0,&dwThreadId);

if(hRemoteThreadHandle!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{

    printf("succeed\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    exit(-1);
}


system("PAUSE");
return 1;
}
```

Below is the result. `WriteProcessMemory` function fails,with the error 487,which means the address is invalid.

[image: Error message]

But the address is the return value of `VirtualAllocEx` function,the return value is not null, so the address should be available.  I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Just a typo.  You're passing `&dwProcBaseAddress` to WriteProcessMemory when you meant to pass `dwProcBaseAddress`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When faced with an error code, look it up. It is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx. You have 487, which is `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS`. The associated description is:

> Attempt to access invalid address.

So, let's dig deeper. If there is an invalid address, what could it be? The two addresses you pass to the function are in the second and third arguments. Certainly the first one, `lpBaseAddress` is wrong. You are meant to pass the address of the memory that you allocated. Instead you pass the address of the variable that contains that address.

I suspect that part of your problem is your erroneous typecasting. `VirtualAllocEx` returns `LPVOID`. Casting that to `DWORD` might be alright for a 32 bit process, but certainly not for a 64 bit process. But why are you casting at all? `LPVOID` is exactly what you need to pass to `WriteProcessMemory`. Your code is littered with erroneous casts. As a broad rule, typecasting the way you do is a code smell that suggests errors. Casting the way you are doing stops the compiler from being able to type check your code.

This is how the base address variable should be declared:

```
LPVOID lpBaseAddress = VirtualAllocEx(...);
```

Then when you call `WriteProcessMemory`, pass that variable:

```
BOOL retval = WriteProcessMemory(..., lpBaseAddress, ...);
```

I don't know why you used `int` for the variable to capture the return value of `WriteProcessMemory`. The documentation has it as `BOOL`. That conveys semantic meaning. You also use `int` for PID. A PID has type `DWORD`.

Not knowing the length of your function could be a problem. What if you cannot read `1024*1024` bytes beyond `create`?

The defect in your program is simple enough. You passed the wrong address. However, I think you need to step back a little. Don't just fix that defect and move on. You really need to spend some time getting on terms with the types that the Win32 API uses. Your wanton typecasting is going to hurt you over and again unless you kick the habit.